# \hrule with vertical margin

Tags: margins, rules

Is it possible to specify a vertical margin for `\rule` or `\hrule`?
When I say

```
abc
\hrule
def
```

the line "touches" the text above and below, so I would like it to have a margin of about 1mm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX doesn't insert interline glue around rules. You need to add the vertical space yourself

```
abc

\vskip1mm
\hrule
\vskip1mm

def
```